# I Want to seperate odd and even numbers in a list and print the original list along with the even and odd list

Tags: prolog

i am able to separate the even and odd from the list but unable to print the original list

```
even_odd([], [], []).
even_odd([X|Xs], [X|Even], Odd) :- 0 is X mod 2,even_odd(Xs, Even, Odd).
even_odd([X|Xs], Even, [X|Odd]) :- 1 is X mod 2,even_odd(Xs, Even, Odd).
```

[image]

i want to print the **original list** along with the even and odd numbers list

Comment: Why not use the [tag:prolog-toplevel] to print it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just say:

```
?- Ns = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], even_odd(Ns,Es,Os) .
```

That should give you:

```
Ns = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
Es = [0,2,4,6,8],
Os = [1,3,5,7,9]
```